# Fading the background while hovering

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I'm duplicating, but I really got stuck in one point and I tried every possible solution about which I've read here and also googling it, failed me.

I want to achieve that when div is hovering, all background is fading. By all background - I mean everything on site beside the hovering div which should appear on the top. 
When div is hovering out, all background should go back to be clear.

Maybe it's simple way to achieve that, but believe me - so far nothing works as I want.. So please - help me :)

```
<body>
<div class="block1">
<div id="text">
  one
</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div id="text">
        two
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Attaching the JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ryfgwswo/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thing you want to implement is called "modal window".   Simple w3School will also guide you http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp   Please comment if it is not exactly you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You want like this?

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#text {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #cfcaca;
}

.block1 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: black;
 border: 2px solid #cfcaca;
 margin: 100px 100px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
}

.block1:hover {
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 border: 2px solid #cfcaca;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 display: block;
 z-index: 100;
}

.block {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #000;
 border: 2px solid #cfcaca;
 margin: 100px 300px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

.block:hover {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300x;
 margin: 100 auto;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 border: 2px solid #cfcaca;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #4e4848;
 display: block;
 z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block1">
    <div id="text">
      one
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
  <div id="text">
   two
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, I want it to be inversely - fading the background while hovering the div :) to be more specific - div should be clear, but other stuff on page should fade..

Answer (score 0):

To apply a hover effect on another div, the second div needs to come second in the HTML.

I simply created a div located inside the body, but after "block1" and "block", and applied a background-color to it as well as an opacity transition.

```
.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(255,0,255);
}

.block:hover + .background {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
}
.block1:hover ~ .background {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
}
```

And HTML :

```
<body>
  <div class="block1">
    <div id="text">
      one
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
        <div id="text">
            two
        </div>
</div>
<div class="background">
</div>
</body>
```

Here's the code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/ryfgwswo/4/

Comment: I probably do not specify enough my problem. I want the div to be clear all the time, but to fade all the page behind. In your example - the pink background should fade while i'm hovering div ONE or div TWO.

Comment: In that case, it's easy. Just add a second hover effect to div 1 (look at my example, I updated it). If that's not what you want, then I haven't understood your problem correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/ryfgwswo/4/

Comment: Ok, that's a simple example, because you can use background div as a static. And what about other divs? (I mean like IMG or text) they must be visible while main div is hovering in and out, but I would like to fade them too. Is it possible in css? Or should I use javascript instead? Admittedly, I would like to use CSS. I also tried to use new div(main) as a new background while hovering target div (in this example call it div ONE). But they can't cooperate - in css neither "+" nor "~", nor even pause between them..